# Анимация исчезновение елемента через keyframes?

Tags: css, css3, html5, анимация

Есть анимация на появления элемента сделана через @keyframes
Как реализовать когда элемент пропадает из DOM

```
@keyframes fade {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
   opacity: 1;
  }
}


.element {
  animation: fade .9s ease;
}
```

Comment: Поменять местами значения opacity. Из DOM, правда, не пропадёт, но видно не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить элемент из DOM только с помощью CSS невозможно. Если вам необходимо просто спрятать элемент, то это можно сделать с помощью вашей же анимации. Как заметил @humster_spb в комментарии, для этого значения свойства `opacity` нужно поменять местами. Но при этом еще добавить значение `forwards` для того, чтобы анимация применила значения свойств элемента к моменту ее окончания и не повторялась.

upd. Можно добавить еще свойство `visibility` и значение `hidden`, чтобы скрыть элемент без изменения разметки документа.

```css
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.element {
  animation: fade 3s ease forwards;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Удалить элемент из DOM дерева с помощью `JavaScript` через заданное время, после выполнения анимации:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.element').remove();
}, 3000);
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.element {
  animation: fade 3s ease forwards;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Ну, значение forwards должно быть и для появления так-то ))

Comment: я бы еще visibility:hidden добавил, чтобы элемент неактивным был.